# Upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 broke all my venvs. How do I fix them?

Tags: upgrade, python, django

I just upgraded my cloud server to 20.04. Unfortunately all of my python django driven websites stopped working because all of my venvs do not work. I can actually activate a venv, but then if I try to use django or even pip it says modules cannot be found. What do I need to do to fix the venvs?

Comment: You can give a try to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62756827/1525392